# Webpage navigation (trouble with bold)

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am building a web page and am trying to get my navigation correct. I am using mysql to store the "subjects" in one table and the "pages" in another table for the website.  It works fine but I am just using bold to represent a page or subject that is selected and for some reason it when I select a subject it bolds the entire list of pages under that subject.  The pages works how I expect (it bolds the page I select).  Here is my PHP page and them my CSS page.  (I suspect it the html class "selected" is getting inhereted but I cant see how).  Any help would be great.

PHP

```
                while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)){
                    echo "<li";
                    if ($subject["id"] == $sel_subj){ echo " class=\"selected\""; }
                    echo"><a href=\"content.php?subj=".urlencode($subject['id']).
                            "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
                    $page_set = get_pages_for_subject($subject['id']);
                    echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
                    while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)){
                        echo "<li";
                        if ($page['id'] == $sel_page){ echo " class=\"selected\""; }
                        echo"><a href=\"content.php?page=".urlencode($page['id']).
                        "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
                ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td id="page">
                    <h2>Content Area</h2>
                    <?php echo $sel_subj;?>
                    <?php echo $sel_page;?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS

```
/*Navigation*/
#navigation { width: 225px; height: 600px; padding: 5% 5%;
             color: #0D8800; background: #44EE44; }
#navigation a { color: #8D0D19; text-decoration: none; }
ul.subjects { padding-left: 0; list-style: none; }
ul.pages { padding-left: 0; list-style: square; }
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off moving the 'selected' class to the 'a' tag.

If that's not an option then you will need to block the inheritance:

```
.selected ul li { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: Thanks Kent,  

I don't know why but all the suden it started working the way I expect.  If I have more problems with it I will move it over